# Building a post using article tags

Tags: html, css

I am building a post item for a website using the article tags and this includes some elements such as an avatar, pot title, post body and post footer, there will also be some controls like a menu icon which shows a menu but I am not to worried about that for now.

I am curious as to the best way to position the layout because it seems a bit messy at the moment and would like this to be a bit more solid and constant.

Here is a demo of what I have done so far.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/zynnLb0x/)

So as you can see it a little messy and I just need some expertise on the best way to lay this out. There is one sticking point that it needs to be responsive but if I could have suggestions on the desktop view of it I can handle the rest but it would be good to get your views.

```
<article class="timeline_posts">

    <div class="timeline_post_avatar">
        avatar
    </div>

    <div class="timeline_post_title">
        post title
    </div>

    <div class="timeline_post_body">
        post body
    </div>

    <div class="timeline_post_footer">
        post footer
    </div>

    <div class="timeline_post_menu">
        menu control
    </div>                                      

</article>


.timeline_posts{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
}






/******* Timeline post body *******/


.timeline_post_avatar{
    background-color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 40px;
}

.timeline_post_title{
    background-color: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
}

.timeline_post_body{
    background-color: green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
}

.timeline_post_footer{
    background-color: yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
}

.timeline_post_menu{
    background-color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: ur layout is correct but ur style have Serious flaw . like u dont give any height or min-height to ur article tag or div

Comment: What are the best ways to approach the flaws in my style...

Comment: I'm trying to write codes for u wait please .

Comment: @mimi I would like to add that the menu needs to be sat in the top right of the post. for some reason it falls down to the bottom right?

Comment: w8 I check that problem for u. and edit the answer

Comment: dont use `width:x%;` as much as u can it make ur code illegible and also when u want to change something in ur layout everything move.

Comment: u can arrange ur tags in different ways ,this way which I write for u is one of that way.u can check another way in the link which I gave to u.I hope it can help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use `width:100%` until u have to. I Usually useing `width:980px; margin:0 auto;`
and also give `height` or `min-height` to ur tags.
if u want to use `width:100%` your style must be like this :
code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
   .container{
     width: 980px;
     min-height: 500px;
     outline: 1px solid red;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .timeline_posts{
     width: 980px;
     min-height: 130px;
     outline: 2px dashed blue;
    }
   .timeline_post_avatar{
     width: 150px;
     height: 130px;
     float: left;
    background: red;
   }
   .timeline_post_title,.timeline_post_body,.timeline_post_footer{
     width: 745px;
     float: left;
     min-height: 44px;
    }
    .timeline_post_title{
     background: green;
    }
    .timeline_post_body{
     background:blue; 
    }
    .timeline_post_footer{
     background: yellow;
    }
    .timeline_post_menu{
     width: 85px;
     height: 30px;
     float: right;
     background: red;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 25px;
     }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container">  
     <article class="timeline_posts">
      <div class="timeline_post_menu">
        menu control
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_post_avatar">
        avatar
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_post_title">
         post title
       </div>
       <div class="timeline_post_body">
         post body
       </div>
       <div class="timeline_post_footer">
         post footer
       </div>
      </div>                                
    </article>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I upload for u a sample to learn how can arrange ur div beside each other 
look at this **s[link](https://github.com/m-kafiyan/layout-sample)** : it easy learn how u can make layout in correct way

Comment: the demo you have provided is not better or worse than what I have produced? The problem with your demo is that it is a fixed width and not liquid or responsive in any way? Plus the controls on the menu are still not sitting in the correct place?

Comment: @stackers I said before u can produce ur layout in different way and becuse of that I gave u that link,if u want be responsive u can give ur avatar `float:left;` and for ur menu `float:right;` and put ur other divs in one mother div.in the link which I put ,u can see lots of sampel.